# declare Google api key in manifest (For youtube API)

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

Using the maps API i can declare my key in manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AlOtOfNumBersAndLetters123" />
```

But in the Youtube API i have to do it programatically (AFAIK):

```
String API_KEY = "AlOtOfNumBersAndLetters123";
youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, myOnInitializedListener);
```

How can I use the key declared in the manifest for Youtube API as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the existing **meta-data** or define a custom one in the *AndroidManifest*:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.my.app.myYoutubeID" android:value="AlOtOfNumBersAndLetters123" />
```

And use it at runtime (both for the dedicated or the existing meta-data):

```
String API_KEY = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData.getString("com.my.app.myYoutubeID");
//String API_KEY = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData.getString("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"); //this will use the Maps meta-data
youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, myOnInitializedListener);
```

Comment: great edit, was just going to ask if it was possible to sneak-peak on the other key.

Comment: @AkselWillgert yay, I've initially misread the question, than I merged both my thoughts ;)